# Finding the largest 3-clique-free induced subgraph

Tags: algorithms, graphs, optimization

Consider this problem:

> Given an undirected graph $G = (V, E)$, find $G' = (V', E')$ such that:
>
> 1. $G'$ is an induced subgraph of $G$
> 2. $G'$ has no 3-cliques
> 3. $|V'|$ is maximal

So the least number of vertices must be eliminated from $G$ so that 3-cliques are eliminated.

An equivalent problem would be to find a 2-coloring for $G$ such that if $(v_1, v_2, v_3) \in V$ and $((v_1, v_2), (v_2, v_3), (v_3, v_1)) \in V$,

1. $(v_1.color == v_2.color \wedge v_2.color == v_3.color \wedge v_3.color == v_1.color) = False$
2. The (absolute) difference between the number of nodes with color 1 and the number of nodes with color 2 is maximal.

Can anyone think of a polynomial-time algorithm to solve one of these problems?

Comment: Do you know that there *is* a polynomial time algorithm, or are you just hoping for one?

Comment: I just realized, your two definitions of the problem don't match! The second imposes the condition that subgraph induced by $V-V'$ is also triangle free. I know that it is NP-Complete to even determine if such a partition exists: http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/65/h-free-cut-problem. While the initial description allows the induced graph of $V-V'$ to contain triangles. Which one is the correct one?

Comment: @LukeMathieson: I believe a class o graphs have polynomial-time solutions because I reached the problem above from the following problem which has polynomial-time solution: "Given a set of N integer intervals, pick as many as possible so that no 3 intersect."

Comment: @Alexandre: Interval graphs are special. Well known NP-Hard problems are in P, when restricted to interval graphs.

Comment: @Aryabhata: The induced subgraph is G', and it cannot have any 3-cliques. Therefore, it cannot have any triangles, exactly the same as the second description.

Comment: @Alexandre: No. By colouring with two colours, you have _two_ induced graphs $G'$ and $G''$. The 1) applies to both as stated. (and you have a typo I suppose, you have $V$ instead of $E$). One implies the other, but they are not equivalent.

Comment: @Aryabhata: I read over the H-free cut problem but the definition says that both subgraphs induced by the cut are H-free. In my problem, only one of them needs to be H-free.

Comment: @Alexandre: Did you check the answer I just added? There are _two_ links, one for each definition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both definitions leave your problem NP-hard, and have been answered on cstheory.

- Interpretation 1, where you require the largest triangle free sub-graph, is NP-Hard and has been answered [here](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/966/computation-of-max-h-free-sets).
- Intepretation 2, where you need a partition such that both the induced sub-graphs are triangle free, has been answered [here](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/65/h-free-cut-problem).

Note that the answers I linked to are for general $H$-freeness and are a class of $NP$-Hard problems.